# Procedure to find generators of the dual cone

Tags: convex-analysis, toric-geometry

Page 11 of Fulton's "Toric Varieties" gives the following procedure for finding generators of the dual of a convex polyhedral cone in $\mathbb{R}^d$:

> For each set of $n-1$ independent vectors among the generators of $\sigma,$ solve for a vector $u$ annihilating the set; if neither $u$ or $-u$ is nonnegative on all generators of $\sigma$ it is discarded; otherwise either $u$ or $-u$ is taken as a generator for $\sigma^{\vee}.$

What does it mean to annihilate the set? I suspect it means that $\langle u, \cdot \rangle$ vanishes on the set, but then $u=0$ trivially always works. Should he have said $u$ must be non-zero? He never said what $n$ is, I guessed it is the number of generators of $\sigma.$ But then, if we found a $u$ that annihilates $n-1$ of the $n$ generators, then one of $u$ or $-u$ is certainly nonnegative on all generators, so we would never throw any of these $u$ away. Can someone clarify what the correct steps are?

Comment: I just found this question because I also don't understand this statement. But I'm pretty sure that $n$ ist the dimension von the vector space $V$.

Comment: Indeed, $u$ should be nonzero, and $n$ is the dimension, so the annihilator of $n-1$ independent vectors is one-dimensional, and so $u$ is unique up to a nonzero scalar. The number of generators of the original cone can have many more generators, so $u$ in general will be positive on some of the generators while negative on the others.